# Declare multiple var's that have multiple if's, but do ANY of the if's, not one, all, or none. [HTML + JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html

Something like this:

```
<!-- HTML on page -->

<!-- hide the following div by class-->
<div id="bed" class="blankets"> 
    We sell blankets
</div>

<!-- hide the following div by ID -->
<div id="animal" class="frogs">
    We sell frogs
</div>

<!-- this is the only div I want visible -->
<div id="house" class="speakers">
    We sell houses and speakers
</div>

<!-- hide the following div by class -->
<div id="car" class="suvs">
    We sell cars
</div>
```

JavaScript to inject on page via UserScript and compatible with GreaseMonkey, Safari, Google Chrome and Opera.

```
var div = document.getElementById("animal"); 

if (div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
};

var cur_columns = document.getElementsByClassName('blankets');
var cur_columns = document.getElementsByClassName('suvs');

if (div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
};
```

I only want to see the content in the middle of the page, while if the top ever changes server side value, but bottom stays the same, the bottom will still hide, now I jut have to update the code to the value.

What I see on the internet are only ways to execute ONE variable, IF the matches ALL, OR (one of the other). It HAS to match a whole rule to a single point.

I would like this to work on the browsers mentioned in the comment please.
I also don't know how to use comments. I've use // and /* */, is /* *\ the way to close a comment?

UPDATE

Now how do I add another line for the var on Class so that I can hide a 4th div?

Comment: Can you be more specific in the description?

Comment: Nicholas, this part isn't at all clear: "I only want to see the content in the middle of the page, while if the top ever changes server side value, but bottom stays the same, the bottom will still hide, now I jut have to update the code to the value." — can you elaborate? Try to write a list of conditions and outcomes (in pseudo-code) explaining the various possibilities and what you would want to happen in each situation.

Comment: Updated my code. I don't know how to describe the title / description of this post better.

Comment: Your updated code makes no sense. I can explain why it makes no sense, but the real problem is we don't know what you want. Could you please elaborate on what you would like to happen?

Comment: I want the second var to remove BOTH divs that have their class specified, regardless if either of them are valid or invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to work out what you want to achieve here, but I can explain what your current script does:

```
// The variable 'div' refers to <div id="frogs">
var div = document.getElementById("frogs"); 

// If 'div' exists, remove it
if (div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
};

// The variable 'cur_columns' refers to all elements with class="speaker"
var cur_columns = document.getElementsByClassName('speakers');
// ...and now it refers to all elements with class="suvs"!
var cur_columns = document.getElementsByClassName('suvs');

// If 'div' exists, remove it (again)
if (div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
};
```

Comment: I want to hide the 1'st div via it's ID, on my websites I want to be able to specify multiple div's by their class and do the same thing (remove BOTH div's), BUT if one of the class's gets updated, then the code will still execute even though one of the classes's is no longer on the web page. I also want to be able to do this with the ID's of the div's.

Comment: Updated the javascript with valid values.

Comment: I explained more in my code. How else do you need me to explain it,?